# Return nested keys in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm tying to get nested keys from a mongodb record structured like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("ju5ts0m3h4shf0r3x4mpl3"),
    "statuses" : {
        "f1r5t1d1n33dt0f1nd" : {
            "ko status" : [...],
            "ok status" : [...]
        },
        "s3c0nd1d1n33dt0f1nd" : {
            "ko status" : [...],
            "ok status" : [...]
        },
        "th1rd1d1n33dt0f1nd" : {
            "ko status" : [...],
            "ok status" : [...]
        }
}
```

The output I expect is something like this :

```
[
    "f1r5t1d1n33dt0f1nd",
    "s3c0nd1d1n33dt0f1nd",
    "th1rd1d1n33dt0f1nd",
]
```

**I need to get the ids only**, because under `"ok status"` and `"ko status"` are large amounts of data, so it could impact performance.

---

I searched through the mongo doc and SO, but found nothing.

How could I query this with PHP MongoClient and/or plain mongodb queries ? It it possible ?

Comment: The only way to do this is with MapReduce. But I suggest you change the documents structure and make "statues" properties a field's value.

Comment: @SSDMS Can I ask you how you do this with MapReduce ?
I could change the structure like you suggest. But I also need to perform a query to find all `ko status` for a given id (this is not part of this specific question), and I couldn't do it with the structure you mentionned, altough I could do it easily with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) like,

```
$status = array_keys($obj['statuses']);
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to load only the keys, for performance concerns.
Although you answer is correct, it would load all sub-document nested underneath.